# How to make sure that regex is not in [] or {}?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to replace all the word in a give sentence with a random word list. Here is my code:

```py
import re
import random

WORDS = ["Brawk" , "Buh-gok", "Bok bok", "Bawk"] # My random word list
PATTERN = r"([a-zA-Z0-9\']+)"
DELIMITER = " "

def callback(matchobj):
    return random.choice(WORDS)

def parse_sentence(sentence):
    return re.sub(PATTERN, callback, sentence)
```

When I run the code, this is what happens:

```
>>> print(parse_sentence("some text's[color=#ff8a00]smoe more text[/color]{n}"))
Bok bok Bok bok[Buh-gok=#Buh-gok]Bok bok Buh-gok Buh-gok[/Bawk]{Brawk}
```

I need it to be `Buh-gok Bok bok[color=#ff8a00]Bok bok Bok bok Bawk[/color]{n}`, so is there anyway to ignore it if it is inside `[]` or `{}`?

Comment: you want to replace all words but not the ones within `[] or {}`?

Comment: @python_user Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify two things in the code:

```py
PATTERN = r"(\[[^][]*]|\{[^{}]*})|[a-zA-Z0-9']+"

def callback(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(1) or random.choice(WORDS)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CMBvQs).

The regex - `(\[[^][]*]|\{[^{}]*})|[a-zA-Z0-9']+` - matches and captures into Group 1 all substrings between square brackets and between curly braces and just matches alphanumeric character chunks, and `return matchobj.group(1) or random.choice(WORDS)` returns either Group 1 values (if Group 1 matched), or the random words if Group 1 did not match.

*Pattern details*:

- `(` - start of a capturing group #1

  - `\[[^][]*]` - `[`, then any zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`, and then a `]` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\{[^{}]*}` - `{`, then any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`, and then a `}` char
- `)` - end of the group
- `|` - or
- `[a-zA-Z0-9']+` - one or more ASCII letters or digits or `'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the explanation is great and it fixed the problem, I'll accept in a few mins.

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal I see, I have not seen the `'` when I copied it from your question. There is no need escaping it here.